# Using Continue in a While loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

Please help me to find out my mistake(s) in this code.

```
var  numbers = [12, 34, 23, 98, 08, 78, 73, 48];
var i = 0;

while (i < numbers.length){
    if (numbers[i] >70){
        continue;
    }
    console.log(numbers[i])
    i++;
}
```

I want to get output

```
12
34
23
8 
48
```

But the code shows output:

```
12
34
23
```

and the **run doesn't stop.**

Comment: You have to increment `i` before you `continue`

Comment: Hint: The continue also skips the `i++`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an infinite loop, because if `numbers[i] > 70` it's not increasing `i`, so the next loop it's checking that same condition again without an incremented `i` value. There are multiple ways to fix this, but one option is to output the value when `numbers[i] <= 70`, and always increment `i`.

```js
var numbers = [12, 34, 23, 98, 08, 78, 73, 48];
var i = 0;

while (i < numbers.length){
    if (numbers[i] <= 70){
        console.log(numbers[i]);
    }
    
    i++;
}
```

Another option would be a different loop:

```js
var numbers = [12, 34, 23, 98, 08, 78, 73, 48];
var i = 0;

for(i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] > 70){
       continue;
    }
    
    console.log(numbers[i]);
}
```

Or a simpler way:

```js
var numbers = [12, 34, 23, 98, 08, 78, 73, 48];
var i = 0;

for(i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] <= 70){
        console.log(numbers[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update `i` value before using `continue` if you don't the value of `i` will remain the same which leads to the loop becoming an infinite loop.

```js
var  numbers = [12, 34, 23, 98, 08, 78, 73, 48];
var i = 0;

while (i < numbers.length){
    if (numbers[i] >70){
        i++;
        continue;
    }
    console.log(numbers[i])
    i++;
}
```

Comment: _while_ this would work (see what I did there?) I'd highly recommend not adding another `i++`. Duplicating basic code logic like this could easily lead to future bugs because it's non-standard.

Comment: Thanks! I see what u'r trying to say

Answer (score 1):

Instead of interrupting the `while` loop you can re-write your logic as:

```
  if (numbers[i] < 71){
    console.log(numbers[i]);
  }
```

so that the default action on each iteration of the loop is simply to increment `i` and, separately, the console logs a value *only if the condition is satisfied*.

---

**Working Example:**

```js
let numbers = [12, 34, 23, 98, 08, 78, 73, 48];
let i = 0;

while (i < numbers.length){

  if (numbers[i] < 71){
    console.log(numbers[i]);
  }
  
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Note: the inverse logic of `numbers[i] > 70` is not `numbers[i] < 71` unless `numbers[i]` can only be an integer. The logical inverse is `numbers[i] <= 70`.

Comment: Ah. Yest, good point, @WOUNDEDStevenJones - I wasn't thinking about _floats_.